# How to fix spelling mistakes and typos when edits must have minimum length?

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across an answer which misspelled a keyword a couple of times.  I wanted to fix it as the answer wasn't bad but the typo made it seem not worth reading.  Unfortunately I was stymied by the minimum limit on edits (which must be 6 characters or more, I think).  What's the correct way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character limit only applies to suggested edits. The reason the limit exists is that suggested edits need to be reviewed by at least two people, and it's quite rare that a minor edit will be worth two reviewers' time. Once you reach 2K rep points [your edits will go through without review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), and the character limit won't apply anymore.

Until then, if you feel a minor edit would make a big difference in a post, you are welcome to drop it in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard) and ask one of the regulars there to edit it for you.

Also, you can always post a comment pointing out the mistakes. The original poster, or any high rep user who'll happen to read your comment can then fix the post.